# VS2012 Generate New Type Error/Bug with Solution Folders

Tags: visual-studio-2012, directory, auto-generate

Whenever I try to use VS2012's built-in "Generate -> New Type..." to create a class **in a different solution folder**, I get the following error message:

*"Generate Type failed: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."*

Only when I move the target project out of the solution folder, into the root of the solution, does it work correctly. Is this behaviour working as intended? Am I doing something wrong? Is it a bug?

Comment: I get this too (except in my case trying to create it in another project in the same solution folder fails too), I guess it's a bug.